# Googlemap api v3 gives an error and not not load map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a Googlemap api v3 with key and it was working fine before sometime. But It stops working from last few days and gives following error in console.

> The Google Maps JavaScript API must be downloaded directly from
>   Google's servers. Learn more: https:
>   //developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API

I read whole document but not get an idea why it happen. I tried all changes and even scripts load perfect but still not shows map. some time after many tries it loads once and than stop working.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Priyank Shah

Comment: We'll need to see some sample code if we are to help you. In particular please paste the `<script>` tags you use for loading the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other random js from the page might be affecting your map loading. I faced the same error and changing away with some parts helped. Try commenting irrelevant js from the page and check and if it works out you face a similar problem. Then keep on uncommenting untill you reach the problematic script.

Comment: yes Jeremy Cal, you are right one of my script create an issue. So I load map apis script first and it works fine.